# Cannot change display settings

Tags: unity, display, 15.04, settings

I go to the **Settings** :

[image: All Settings]

Then I click on the **Displays** tab under **Hardware** category and get the following:

[image: Displays]

I am afraid cannot fix it up.

**Edit:**
Output of `xrandr`

[image: Output of <code>xrandr</code>]

**Edit 2:**
The `gnome-shell` DE was able to read the display information what the `Unity` DE couldn't:

[image]

Comment: what is the output of `xrandr` in a terminal ?

Comment: @solsTiCe: see edit section of the post.

Comment: What do you want to change ? then look at [man page of xrandr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/xrandr.1.html) for that...

Comment: There is a file: `~/.config/monitors.xml`. possibly (most likely) for some reason, the file is corrupted and unreadable. Try removing/renaming the file, log out and back in. Then try again using System Settings.

Comment: @solsTiCe apart from setting the monitor, OP probably would like to solve the problem of not being able to do so from GUI.

Comment: Ashubuntu, could you give some feedback on the answer(s)? Would be useful to understand what works or not.

Comment: @JacobVlijm When I logged into my machine using the Unity DE, I got that problem in the first place. Then I installed gnome-shell and logged in, now I get the normal case. See Edit 2 Section. I guess my Unity DE is somehow broken.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue on 15.04,I managed to resolve it by installing unity-control-center.

I guess somewhere down the line I had messed it up or removed it.

Try reinstalling it if its already there....

`sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`

Comment: I did as you said and got my problem partially solved. If you look at the screen-shot I added in **Edit 2**, you will notice that at the right there is _Dell Inc. 19_ and at the left there is the default 15.04 background with the number 1 pinned on it. This time my machine can read the screen information _Dell Inc. 19_ at the right but cannot output the background at the left that I have changed from default ubuntu 15.04 to another one.

Comment: @Ajinkya Patil Thanks!  same issue , I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Its a bug,**Gnome** is full of it, try to do this in terminal (**Ctrl**+**Alt**+**T**):-

```
mutter --replace
```

Otherwise you can replace the **Gnome Desktop Environment**. Try to install another environment. By the way, can you tell me your **Ubuntu** version?

=>**EDIT**=<

Ok, Try to do this:-

```
xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1366x768_59.8
xrandr --output VGA --mode 1366x768_59.8
```

Comment: Desktop Environment is Unity, Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Are you using laptop or pc? And how many monitors/projectors are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same problem on 16.04

I solved it by changing the graphical card driver in the settings. (Changed from the default repo to the Nvidia report)

[Driver settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx7hv.png)